# Overpass API FILE_ERROR Operation not permitted 1

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap, dispatcher, overpass-api

I am following this http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation guide to install OSM3S server on Ubuntu using vagrant.

After populating DB whenever i try to Start Dispatcher Deomon using the command:

```
nohup $EXEC_DIR/bin/dispatcher --osm-base --db-dir=$DB_DIR &
```

I get the following error:

> File_Error Operation not permitted 1
>   /vagrant/test/osm-3s_v0.7.52/db//**osm3s_v0.7.52_osm_base**
>   Unix_Socket::4

If i try to rename the osm file in my db directory from osm_base_version to **osm3s_v0.7.52_osm_base** it gives the following error:

> File_Error Address already in use 98
>   /vagrant/test/osm3s_v0.7.52/db//osm3s_v0.7.52_osm_base Unix_Socket::4

I tried to run the command after removing the stale lock files /dev/shm and osm file in db directory (mentioned the Troubleshooting section of installation guide) but it shows no success .

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/52278/overpass-api-file_error-operation-not-permitted-1

Comment: Updated the overpass api version to 0.7.53 but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by working on root instead of working on separate directory in root .